# Which is the correct Electrolux replacement element?

Tags: oven

I'm confused over a replacement part for my oven. It's an IKEA model manufactured by Electrolux. The PNC is `94406450601`

According to Electrolux (and every third party spares site) the correct fan element for this oven is [3970123018](https://shop.electrolux.co.uk/Cooking/Cookers-Ovens-%26-Hobs/Heating-Elements/2000-Watt-Fan-Oven-Heating-Element/p/3970123018) which is illustrated as a triple loop.

[image]

However, my old part is a double (not triple) loop and has the part number etched onto it as `397012801`. Electrolux told me over the phone that this number is nothing to do with them and yet a [product does exist](https://shop.electrolux.co.uk/Cooking/Cookers-Ovens-%26-Hobs/Heating-Elements/2000W-Oven-Circular-Fan-Element/p/3970128017) by that number that looks identical to my faulty part. (double loop)

[image]

I note that the product number is suffixed with "7" giving `3970128017`, but it seems too much of coincidence that the first 9 digits match and it looks the same.

Can anyone explain why the correct part looks completely wrong, but the other supposedly incompatible part looks like the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a new element superseded the old. Electrolux is the parent to many brands, but from reading, Ikea, USA, ovens are rebranded Whirlpool. Try a whirpool part search. Either part should work, as long as the specs match, and the 3 turn fits in the hole. The part number listed on the part is the best choice for a direct replacement.

Comment: Thanks. The only specs given are the same (2000W/230V) and also physical size. But suppliers refuse to say if whether the "wrong" one will work.

Comment: I would buy the part with the same part number as the one you have. Unless that part has failed quickly, it is possible it was the wrong one installed to begin with.

Comment: It's a 2kW/230V resistor, it will work, the problem is if it fits into the space in oven itself